# Auto click a link without class and ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and trying to get all the links from a menu in a site. But unfortunately, the menu list doesn't automatically show everything, you'd have to click the 
"View All" link first which is made from JavaScript.

So I'm thinking that I need to autoclick that "View All" first before proceeding to the codes for getting the links. The page source looks like this

```
  <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="javascript: void(0)">View All</a>
  </li>
```

Any ideas on how I'd autoclick the link without having an id or a class in the anchor tag itself? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the desired anchor tag with `:contains()` selector since we don't have any relevant identity to it and invoke its click event by using `.trigger('eventName')`

Try,

```
$('.menu-item a:contains("View All")').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Who downvoted though? Lol. Thanks a lot. :) It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** or **[.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/)**,

```
$('a:contains("View All")').click();
```

or

```
$('.menu-item a:contains("View All")').click();
```

or

```
$('.menu-item a').contains("View All").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu-item a:contains("View All")').trigger('click');
```

or can try

```
$('.menu-item a:contains("View All")').click();
```

Comment: may be duplicate answer but i don't

Comment: Downvoting without comment? why?